# creating a new associated object through build always sets some columns to nil in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, field, has-many, null

I have a simple one-to-many relationship between user and micropost as below.  I tried to add a new column called `stage` to the Micropost model.  when I try to build a new Micropost and save, the `stage` column is always automatically set to `nil`.  I have tried `create`, `build` - doesn't matter, the `stage` field is always set to `nil`. I am baffled, please help!

```
$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.5)
>> User.first.microposts.create!( :stage => "p", :content => "test 6" )

=> #<Micropost id: 2, content: "test 6", stage: nil, user_id: 1, created_at: "2011-04-23 22:14:20", updated_at: "2011-04-23 22:14:20">
```

...

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :stage
  attr_accessor :stage

  belongs_to :user

  validates :content, :presence => true, :length => { :maximum => 140 }
  validates :user_id, :presence => true

  default_scope :order => 'microposts.created_at DESC'
  scope :from_users_followed_by, lambda { |user| followed_by(user) }

  private
    def self.followed_by(user)
      followed_ids = %( SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                        WHERE follower_id = :user_id)
  where "user_id IN (#{followed_ids}) OR user_id = :user_id",
                                      { :user_id => user }  
    end

end
```

...

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :password
    attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

    has_many :microposts, :dependent => :destroy  
end
```

Comment: Is `stage` a real column in the DB or just an attribute in the model?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove line:

```
attr_accessor :stage
```

Without it everything works fine. I think it's conflict between `attr_accessor` and `attr_accessible`.